# When I click on connect to quickbooks, the resulting pop up window has a blank session. How can I fix this?

Tags: php, session, quickbooks, multi-tenant

I'm using QuickBooks PHP DevKit from consolibyte.  I was unable to locate the version number, but it was a recent nightly build.  I am attempting to connect to a QuickBooks Online installation using the sample files in
docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/ as a base.

The `tenant_id` for my application is stored in the session. When I click on the 'Connect to Quickbooks' button, it brings up `oauth.php` in a new window.  The `tenant_id` is always blank because the entire session is missing, despite the `session_start();` that I've added to `oauth.php`.

How can I get the session variable to show up?  If the `tenant_id` needs to be added to the url, where do I add it? I don't see any way to modify the behavior of clicking on the `<ipp:connectToIntuit></ipp:connectToIntuit>` button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out what was going on.  In the config file, I had `$quickbooks_oauth_url="https://myserver.com/oauth.php"` 
instead of 
`"https://www.myserver.com/oauth.php"`.

Since I was coming from `https://www.myserver.com`, it was treating `https://myserver.com/oauth.php` as a different website with a different session.  Now that I've added the `www` to the config file, it's working as expected.